# Find the point with radius and angle

Tags: actionscript-3, geometry

I'm not a genius in geometry, I'd like to find a point in `as3` with the `radius` and a `angle` but I don't remember the rule, I know this should be simple!

Here's an example:

[alt text http://img297.imageshack.us/img297/4879/examplepr.png](http://img297.imageshack.us/img297/4879/examplepr.png)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
as3.x = centerX + radius * cos(angle)
as3.y = centerY + radius * sin(angle)
```

Note that the rotation in the picture linked to is in the "negative direction". I.e, an increase of the angle, yields a counter-clockwise rotation.

Comment: thanks for the note and for the help, can you eventually check what's wrong here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887725/drawing-an-honeycomb-with-as3 thanks again

Answer (score 4):

Let x0, y0 be the center of the circle being considered and t be the angle theta anti-clockwise from the x-axis (right horizontal).

The point you are looking for is then

```
x = x0 + r*cos(t)
y = y0 + r*sin(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to adjust your calculator to degree mode before making that calculation
more likley you will use angle in degree