# How to adjust rotation of a SKSpriteNode

Tags: sprite-kit, rotation, trigonometry

I've been working on a top view game, where there're two virtual joysticks present to control a character. For the joysticks, I've used [Spritekit-Joystick](https://github.com/Derrick56007/SpriteKit-Joystick). The character shoots automatically. The right Joystick is used for changing direction, and I have implemented this function to move the character:

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    if (self.imageJoystick.velocity.x != 0 || self.imageJoystick.velocity.y != 0)
    {
        myCharacter.zRotation = self.imageJoystick.angularVelocity;
    }

}
```

For the `self.imageJoystick.angularVelocity`, the Joystick library uses this code (the code is available from the link above, but just for the sake of making things easier and more readily available):

```
    angularVelocity = -atan2(thumbNode.position.x - self.anchorPointInPoints.x, thumbNode.position.y - self.anchorPointInPoints.y);
```

There' a problem with the rotation. When I push the joystick (thumbnode) up, the rotation points to the right. I've used NSLog to get the value, and it shows around 0. When I push the joystic (thumbnode above) to the left, the character points upwards, and I get around 1.5 reading for angularVelocity. Pushing it down points the character to left and gives a -3 reading. Finally, when I push right, I point the character to South, and geta reading of around 1.5.

The same thing happens with the 'bullets' I shoot out. For now I'm using beams, which I found the answer in this [POST] on here[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22920495/shoot-from-rotating-body). I have added it below for your convenience (Not my answer, but I've changed it to be used in my game):

```
[[self childNodeWithName:@"RayBeam"]removeFromParent];
int x = myCharacter.position.x + 1000 * cos(myCharacter.zRotation);
int y = myCharacter.position.y + 1000 * sin(myCharacter.zRotation);

SKShapeNode* beam1 = [SKShapeNode node];
CGMutablePathRef pathToDraw = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, myCharacter.position.x, myCharacter.position.y);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, x, y);
beam1.path = pathToDraw;
[beam1 setStrokeColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[beam1 setName:@"RayBeam"];
[self addChild:beam1];
```

The exact same thing happens. When I 1) push the joystick up, I shoot to right. 2) push the joystick  to the left, I shoot Upward. 3) push downward, I shoot left, and 4) when I push the joystick to the right, I shoot downward.

I think I need to tweek the math and trigonometry equations, but maths isn't my forte, and I'm relatively new to this.

The image below is the image of the game (it's not completed at all), and you can see I'm pushing up but I'm pointing, and shooting to right.

[image]

Note: my sprite is also point to the right by default. I tried rotating all my sprites counter clockwise, and that works with the sprites, but not with the beam.

I really appreciate your help.

Thank you in advance.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If up is `0 radians` then you should be calculating your beam's `x` and `y` with:

```
int x = myCharacter.position.x - 1000 * sin(myCharacter.zRotation);
int y = myCharacter.position.y + 1000 * cos(myCharacter.zRotation);
```

Comment: Perfect again Dion! Thanks a lot for your answer.