# AS3 extra movement along a linear path

Tags: actionscript-3, math, actionscript

I'm trying to make a shmup and trying to make a specific "bullet pattern". Basically, I have an enemy fire a number of bullets displaced around a circle. Let's say that that circle of bullets is going to the right. Next, I want the circle to collapse upon itself so I add a second impulse to the x & y velocities of the bullet. Essentially so that the shape of the bullets being fired looks something like this as it travels (I hope this shoddy symbolization makes sense):

```
O  o  •  o  O
```

That works.

Then I just want it to collapse it's vertical positioning, not horizontally so it would look like this:

```
O  —  O
```

I can also do this. BUT, if I try to shoot this circle diagonally, or in a direction other than perfectly horizontally or vertically it breaks down a bit.

Here is the code I'm working with, the section with clusterGrowthX & Y is the part i'm having trouble with. The solution is probably staring me right in the face but I can't figure it out right now. Any questions, just ask. Thanks.

```
            for(var j:int = 0; j < _info.clusterAmount; j++)
            {
                var around  : Number = _info.angle - (_info.clusterRange/2) + (_info.clusterRange/_info.clusterAmount/2) + j * (_info.clusterRange/_info.clusterAmount);
                var xOff    : Number = (Math.cos(around) * _info.clusterRadius);
                var yOff    : Number = (Math.sin(around) * _info.clusterRadius);

                var bullet = new _info.bulletShape(_info);
                bullet.x = startPoint.x + xOff;
                bullet.y = startPoint.y + yOff;
                if(_info.dParent is PlayerControl)
                {
                    bullet.x += Math.cos(_info.angle) * 40;
                    bullet.y += Math.sin(_info.angle) * 40;
                }
                var sign    : Number = (_info.angle < 0) ? -1 : 1;

                trace(Math.cos(around),Math.sin(around));

                bullet.info.vx += Math.cos(around) * _info.clusterGrowthX;
                bullet.info.vy += Math.sin(around) * _info.clusterGrowthY;

                bullet.rotation = _info.angle * 180 / Math.PI;
                _info.dLevel.addChild(bullet);
            }
```

Comment: I guess this should help you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17246/is-there-a-way-to-rotate-the-graph-of-a-function (After applying the first rotation transform to follow the circling pattern, you can't rotate using sin cos anymore you have to use rotation matrices). I faced this problem: So I created a new matrix object -> translated by x|y -> rotated the matrix with built in function -> plug back x|y or you could delve into matrix calculations yourself.

Comment: Ha ha, +1 for teaching me the term [shmup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoot_'em_up). I've been shmupping for almost my entire life and didn't even know it.

Comment: If it is working when its perfectly horizontal, just put it in a container Sprite and rotate and move that as you need, your calculations then wont be affected by it because the bullet will always be relative to its container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is have your clusterGrowth increase and decrease along an arbitrary angle.

So how do we project a point along an arbitrary angle?

```
var amountOfOffset:Number = 10// how far along the angle you want to go.
var angleInDegrees:Number = 45; // this is the angle you want it to expand on.
var angleInRadians:Number = angleInDegrees * 0.0174532925;
clusterGrowthX = amountOfOffset * cos(angleInRadians);
clusterGrowthY = amountOfOffset * sin(angleInRadians);
```

That should do you.

What you're asking is very much the same as finding a point on a circle:
[Find the point with radius and angle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887513/find-the-point-with-radius-and-angle)

Comment: Thanks, never thought to do that haha

Answer (score 0):

Tween / Tweenlite library. Fixes all your problems ^_^ simple, easy, clean, optimized to heavens.