# Plotting points around a semicircle with x y coordinates

Tags: javascript

Im trying to use a forumla to convert degrees into X and Y coordinates, so that I can place points around the circumference of a circle with CSS by means of "top" and "left" offsets.

These posts describe trigonomic functions to help with this:

- [Find the point on a circle with given center point, radius, and degree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096138/find-the-point-on-a-circle-with-given-center-point-radius-and-degree?rq=1)
- [Find the point with radius and angle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887513/find-the-point-with-radius-and-angle?rq=1)

Dozens of searches keep bringing up this formula:

```
X = r * cosine(angle)
Y = r * sine(angle)
```

But I cannot get it to work in the context of my code. This code:

```
// angle is amount in degrees that the point should be at
// pieHeight is distance between bottom of semicircle and top of semicircle (i.e. radius)
var angle = ((amount / range) * 180);
offLeft = pieHeight + ((pieHeight) * Math.cos(angle));
offTop = (pieHeight / 3) + ((pieHeight) * Math.sin(angle));
console.log(amount, angle, Math.round(offLeft), Math.round(offTop));

// Update display
$(val).css('left', offLeft);
$(val).css('top', offTop);
```

Yields this result:

[image: Incorrect dials]

Console output is:

```
0 0 268 45
20 36 117 -88
40 72 4 79
60 108 184 169
80 144 251 -21
100 180 54 -63
```

The numbers are in a circular arc as the should be, but they are not in order, and I can't get them to conform to be within only a semicircle.
Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that [Math.sin()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sin) and [Math.cos()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/cos) take an angle in radians. I guess you are multiplying by 180 to get an angle in degrees.

Try changing

```
var angle = ((amount / range) * 180);
```

with

```
var angle = ((amount / range) * Math.PI);
```

Comment: Legend! Thats fixed it. It looks like this now: http://postimg.org/image/cnxuginfb/ I just need to adjust some offsets and invert some numbers and it will be functioning as expected.